# How to make values transfer between multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two threads:

Thread 1 is fetching XML from a web service in loop.

Thread 2 is parsing the XML fetched by thread 1 and showing it in the UI.

Please tell me what is the best way to pass XML data from thread 1 to thread 2 as it’s retrieved by thread 1?

Thread 1 is fetching the XML and then thread 2 consuming it.

To do so i have created a circular linked list and thread 1 puts its XML there in the linked list and thread 2 gets the XML for it and remove it from the list, and it’s working fine.

Please tell me if there is any other better approach than what I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need

[Producer-Consumer Quequ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thaks for quick and very usefull reply.

Comment: FYI...the implementation of the producer-consumer pattern in that article is **not** correct. Microsoft really needs to purge that article.

Answer (score 2):

The framework provides

> [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)

with .NET 4.0. It should implement a queue between consumer and producer without the need of any manual synchronisation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .Net 4.0 you can use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), this is a Producer-Consumer Queue which allows the consumer to wait for more work from the producer without you having to manage the interaction.